# Why does changing the window class name affect the exit code of a Win32 program?

Tags: windows, winapi, exit-code

Why does closing the created window result in an exit code of 134 (0x86) in the reproducible code example below?

What I also found, is that changing the `const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]` variable results in a different exit code. Increasing the class name with 1 character, increases the exit code with 2, it seems.

What I would expect from this code, is an exit code of 0, right? What is causing this?

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ PWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nShowCmd) {
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"AFEWCHARACTERS";

    WNDCLASSW wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    RegisterClassW(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW(
        0,
        CLASS_NAME,
        L"Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        hInstance,
        nullptr
    );

    if (hwnd != nullptr) {
        ShowWindow(hwnd, nShowCmd);
    }

    MSG msg{};
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: i'm failing to see any return statement in your `WinMain()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code exhibits **undefined behavior**, as your `wWinMain()` function is missing a required `return` statement after its message loop finishes:

```
    MSG msg{};
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }

    return 0; // or msg.wParam // <-- ADD THIS!
}
```

The return value of `wWinMain()` is used to set the calling process's exit code upon a *graceful* exit (ie, if `ExitProcess()`/`TerminateProcess()` has not been called beforehand, and an uncaught exception has not been thrown). Per the [`GetExitCodeProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess) documentation:

> This function returns immediately. If the process has not terminated and the function succeeds, the status returned is `STILL_ACTIVE` (a macro for `STATUS_PENDING` (`minwinbase.h`)). If the process has terminated and the function succeeds, the status returned is one of the following values:
>
> - The exit value specified in the `ExitProcess()` or `TerminateProcess()` function.
> - **The return value from the `main()` or `WinMain()` function of the process.**
> - The exception value for an unhandled exception that caused the process to terminate.

Only `main()` (which is defined by the C/C++ standards, and thus has special handling) is allowed to omit a `return` statement, in which case its return value will be 0 implicitly.  Any other function with a non-`void` return type **requires** an explicit `return`, otherwise its return value will be *indeterminate*.

Comment: A conforming compiler must issue a diagnostic when a function with a non-`void` return type doesn't return a value. Oddly enough, MSVC [applies the rules for `main`](https://godbolt.org/z/zcdbEEjdE) to functions that use one of the `WinMain` variations as their name (but then forgets to invent the implied default return value).

Comment: I take that back: A conforming compiler need *not* issue a diagnostic when a value-returning function doesn't return a value. It's just UB. I guess MSVC is correct here, even if a bit confusing: It *will* issue a hard error if any value-returning function that's not called `main`/`WinMain` (and variations) doesn't actually return a value.